# What is the meaning of  'T' in the execution permissions of a directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, ls

I just found this confusing output of the `ls` command:

```
    whodare@ubuntu~ $: ls -l /var/spool/cron/
    total 12
    drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 Oct 29 05:02 atjobs
    drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 Sep 15 21:09 atspool
    drwx-wx--T 2 root         crontab  4096 Dec 24 02:11 crontabs
```

I know 't' means sticky, but what does 'T' mean?

How can I setup this bit for a directory?

Answer (score 22):

`t` takes place of `x` so you need to be able to distinguish whether the `x` was supposed to be there and was overwritten by `t`

- `t` == sticky + `x`
- `T` == only sticky

Comment: Why is this not documented in the man page of ```ls```?

Answer (score 9):

Look for sticky bit in [here](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/19060-unix-file-permissions.html).
Regarding your second question, look at [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit#Examples) on how to set it.

The difference between the two is that 'T' is present

> on a file or directory without the execution bit set for the others category

Answer (score 5):

`t` will be in place of others permission and in place of execute permission. So it means that `t` is for execute + sticky bit. `T` means only sticky bit without execute permission.

Example:

```
dr-xr-xr-t  2 scm scm 4096 Feb 15 17:48 log
drwxr-xr-T  2 scm scm 4096 Feb 15 18:04 rpm
```

Here, `log` has execute + sticky bit (others). `rpm` has only sticky bit.